# Spinner using spin.js Not Spinning

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-spinner

Good day Guys,

I am trying to use a spinner that shows on the entire page when i click on Submit button.  The below are the codes snippets.

This is the JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/spin.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
        $("#loading").fadeIn();
        var opts = {
            lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration

             
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('loading');
        //var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        var spinner = new Spin.Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    });
});
```

This is the CSS below

```
#loading {
display: none;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
z-index: 1000;
}

#loadingcontent {
display: table;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#loadingspinner {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: larger;
padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Below is the DIV that holds the searching.

```
 <div id="loading">
        <div id="loadingcontent">
            <p id="loadingspinner">
                Searching things...
            </p>
        </div>
     </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
        <p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AllLoanProcessed", "Transactions", new { area = "Transactions" }, FormMethod.Get))
            {

                <b>Search By:</b>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Account_Number", true) <text>Account Number</text>
                @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Surname") <text> Surname </text> <br />
                @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { placeholder = "Search Value", @class = "form-control" })
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />

            }
        </p>
    </div>
```

The issue is that, when i click on the search button, The spin does not load.
Am I missing something? OR any one has any other spinner method that works that will cover the whole page when running.

EDIT:
The below is the spin.js file content.

```
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
__assign = Object.assign || function (t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
   return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
   };
   var defaults = {
lines: 12,
length: 7,
width: 5,
radius: 10,
scale: 1.0,
corners: 1,
color: '#000',
fadeColor: 'transparent',
animation: 'spinner-line-fade-default',
rotate: 0,
direction: 1,
speed: 1,
zIndex: 2e9,
className: 'spinner',
top: '50%',
left: '50%',
shadow: '0 0 1px transparent',
position: 'absolute',
};
var Spinner = /** @class */ (function () {
function Spinner(opts) {
    if (opts === void 0) { opts = {}; }
    this.opts = __assign(__assign({}, defaults), opts);
}
/**
 * Adds the spinner to the given target element. If this instance is already
 * spinning, it is automatically removed from its previous target by calling
 * stop() internally.
 */
Spinner.prototype.spin = function (target) {
    this.stop();
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.className = this.opts.className;
    this.el.setAttribute('role', 'progressbar');
    css(this.el, {
        position: this.opts.position,
        width: 0,
        zIndex: this.opts.zIndex,
        left: this.opts.left,
        top: this.opts.top,
        transform: "scale(" + this.opts.scale + ")",
    });
    if (target) {
        target.insertBefore(this.el, target.firstChild || null);
    }
    drawLines(this.el, this.opts);
    return this;
    };
/**
 * Stops and removes the Spinner.
 * Stopped spinners may be reused by calling spin() again.
 */
   Spinner.prototype.stop = function () {
    if (this.el) {
        if (typeof requestAnimationFrame !== 'undefined') {
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.animateId);
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(this.animateId);
        }
        if (this.el.parentNode) {
            this.el.parentNode.removeChild(this.el);
        }
        this.el = undefined;
    }
    return this;
    };
    return Spinner;
  }());
 export { Spinner };
/**
 * Sets multiple style properties at once.
 */
function css(el, props) {
for (var prop in props) {
    el.style[prop] = props[prop];
}
return el;
}
/**
 * Returns the line color from the given string or array.
 */
function getColor(color, idx) {
return typeof color == 'string' ? color : color[idx % color.length];
}
/**
 * Internal method that draws the individual lines.
 */
function drawLines(el, opts) {
 var borderRadius = (Math.round(opts.corners * opts.width * 500) / 1000) + 
'px';
var shadow = 'none';
if (opts.shadow === true) {
    shadow = '0 2px 4px #000'; // default shadow
}
else if (typeof opts.shadow === 'string') {
    shadow = opts.shadow;
}
var shadows = parseBoxShadow(shadow);
for (var i = 0; i < opts.lines; i++) {
    var degrees = ~~(360 / opts.lines * i + opts.rotate);
    var backgroundLine = css(document.createElement('div'), {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -opts.width / 2 + "px",
        width: (opts.length + opts.width) + 'px',
        height: opts.width + 'px',
        background: getColor(opts.fadeColor, i),
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        transformOrigin: 'left',
        transform: "rotate(" + degrees + "deg) translateX(" + opts.radius + 
   "px)",
    });
    var delay = i * opts.direction / opts.lines / opts.speed;
    delay -= 1 / opts.speed; // so initial animation state will include trail
    var line = css(document.createElement('div'), {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        background: getColor(opts.color, i),
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
        boxShadow: normalizeShadow(shadows, degrees),
        animation: 1 / opts.speed + "s linear " + delay + "s infinite " + 
 opts.animation,
    });
    backgroundLine.appendChild(line);
    el.appendChild(backgroundLine);
    }
 }
 function parseBoxShadow(boxShadow) {
 var regex = /^\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s+)?(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)([a-zA-Z]*)\s+(-?\d+(\.\d+)?) 
 ([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)$/;
  var shadows = [];
   for (var _i = 0, _a = boxShadow.split(','); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var shadow = _a[_i];
    var matches = shadow.match(regex);
    if (matches === null) {
        continue; // invalid syntax
    }
    var x = +matches[2];
    var y = +matches[5];
    var xUnits = matches[4];
    var yUnits = matches[7];
    if (x === 0 && !xUnits) {
        xUnits = yUnits;
    }
    if (y === 0 && !yUnits) {
        yUnits = xUnits;
    }
    if (xUnits !== yUnits) {
        continue; // units must match to use as coordinates
    }
    shadows.push({
        prefix: matches[1] || '',
        x: x,
        y: y,
        xUnits: xUnits,
        yUnits: yUnits,
        end: matches[8],
      });
    }
   return shadows;
  }
  /**
  * Modify box-shadow x/y offsets to counteract rotation
   */
function normalizeShadow(shadows, degrees) {
var normalized = [];
for (var _i = 0, shadows_1 = shadows; _i < shadows_1.length; _i++) {
    var shadow = shadows_1[_i];
    var xy = convertOffset(shadow.x, shadow.y, degrees);
    normalized.push(shadow.prefix + xy[0] + shadow.xUnits + ' ' + xy[1] + 
 shadow.yUnits + shadow.end);
  }
  return normalized.join(', '); 
}
function convertOffset(x, y, degrees) {
var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
var sin = Math.sin(radians);
var cos = Math.cos(radians);
return [
    Math.round((x * cos + y * sin) * 1000) / 1000,
    Math.round((-x * sin + y * cos) * 1000) / 1000,
   ];
}
```

Comment: Without the `spin.js` file its going to be really hard for us to help you. You should also include your rendered HTML or at least make a code sandbox we can test.

Comment: @disinfor, I will edit it shortly. Thank you